# How Cacti collects data using scripts?

Tags: linux, monitoring, snmp, cacti

We know that Cacti uses SNMP to query and collect data. As far as i know SNMP manager uses Object ID (OID) to query about a certain object and get the response from an SNMP agent regarding that OID.

What confuses me is that how Cacti uses e.g. `perl` or `python` script to collect data? Does it use SNMP then? If so how the protocol works then?

Comment: @krisFR if the language is handling SNMP directly in a script, then they should load the relevant SNMP module first. right? but i am just seeing a plain generic `perl` script to query for memory usage...i think what you probably meant is that the script is first converted into a query, then SNMP using that query..please do correct me..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `Cacti` you are not limited only to SNMP queries.

You can choose to run any script of your own as a Data Input Method. It could be `Perl`, `PHP`, `Python`, `Bash` or whatever. Just choose the Script/Command input type :

[image]

Your script has to output at least one value. This value will be attached to an output field within `Cacti` and used later to create the final graph.

If you only need one output field, just print the value as it is (eg `12`) without anything else (eg `ms`, `%`) :

```
#!/bin/sh
ping -c1 host | grep rtt | cut -d"=" -f2 | cut -d"/" -f2
```

In case you have to retrieve multiple values, the output format has to be :

```
field1:value1 field2:value2 field3:value3
```

Then each field will be attached to an ouput field.

```
#!/bin/sh
result=$(ping -c1 host | grep rtt | cut -d"=" -f2)
min=$(echo $result | cut -d"/" -f1)
avg=$(echo $result | cut -d"/" -f2)
max=$(echo $result | cut -d"/" -f3)
echo "min:$min avg:$avg max:$max"
```

You can find further explanation and examples here :

- http://www.cacti.net/downloads/docs/html/making_scripts_work_with_cacti.html
- http://forums.cacti.net/viewtopic.php?t=11288 (no longer maintained by author but still not deprecated).

Comment: Could you please look at this question?  (https://serverfault.com/questions/973558/how-to-monitor-in-cacti-the-packet-loss-of-linux-server-net-snmp)