# How to monitor in Cacti the packet loss of Linux Server (Net SNMP)

Tags: linux, linux-networking, snmp, cacti, net-snmp

I'm testing my network infrastructure where I'm using **iPerf** and *UDP protocol.*

I'm running *Cacti* an open-source, web-based network monitoring and graphing. **SNMP** server is enabled in Linux servers.

First of all, so far, *Cacti* is able to monitor all template's graphs which are already there (*e.g., Memory, CPU, Average Load, Interface Statistics*) But I could not find the graph for `Packet loss graph` for the Interface. It should be like in Cisco Router `In/Out Errors/Discarded Packets` but maybe with different notation. Does anybody have an idea?

Secondly, I would like also to plot/graph what `netstat` shows. For instance `netstat -su` shows:

```
    Udp:
            1354844 packets received
            0 packets to unknown port received.
            5854 packet receive errors
            1360713 packets sent
            RcvbufErrors: 5854
```

I want to graph the *sent, received packets and the packet receive errors*. Is that possible with `SNMP NETSTAT`. In another words, I'd like to plot **UDP packet loss**.

Is there any python, Perl or bash script that can be used to collect data of `SNMP NETSTAT` for UDP packets? Would be much better if it is SNMP queries.

I tried `snmpnetstat -v2c -c public -Cs -Cp udp 172.0.1.11` where it shows only

```
udp:
```

Then, I tried `snmpnetstat -v2c -c public -Cs 172.0.1.11` but it does not show any values.

```
tcp:
udp:
  ....

          - output errors
         icmp6 histogram:
              input     output type
```

**2nd Edit**

I have written the *bash script* and it returns exactly the output I want when I run for example  `./udp_netstat.sh 172.0.1.11`:

```
    #!/bin/bash

rs="$(snmpnetstat -v2c -c public -Cs -Cp udp "$@")"
    # You have to quote "$rs" so newlines don't break
    ReceivedDatagrams="$(echo "$rs" | cut -d$'\n' -f2 | tr -s ' '| cut -d' ' -f2)"
    InvalidPort="$(echo "$rs" | cut -d$'\n' -f3 | tr -s ' '| cut -d' ' -f2)"
    DroppedDatagrams="$(echo "$rs" | cut -d$'\n' -f4 | tr -s ' '| cut -d' ' -f2)"
    DatagramRequests="$(echo "$rs" | cut -d$'\n' -f5 | tr -s ' '| cut -d' ' -f2)"

    echo "Received Datagrams:$ReceivedDatagrams Invalid port:$InvalidPort Dropped datagrams:$DroppedDatagrams Datagram requests:$DatagramRequests"
```

the value `"$@"` is for the hostname device for cacti

**The output of bash script is:**

```
Received Datagrams:258 Invalid port:63 Dropped datagrams:0 Datagram requests:471520
```

Starting with data input method, I gave the following path `/usr/share/cacti/site/scripts/udp_netstat <hostname>` then I added the input fields as well as the output, according to the bash file output.

For the Data Source, I added data source items also according to the bash file output and made Data source type as **COUNTER**. Then, I proceed to Graph Template where I added the line of each output I have.

It seems to be in the workflow of adding new script, however, nothing so far is shown in the graph.

I assume there is a mistake with the Input String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be to use the `snmpnetstat` command that comes with the `snmp` package.

It allows to query statistics per protocols using `-Cs` and `-Cp` parameters :

> snmpnetstat [COMMON OPTIONS] [-Ca] [-Cn] [-Cs] [-Cp protocol] AGENT
>
> **-Cs** Show per-protocol statistics.
>
> **-Cp** *protocol* Show statistics about protocol

https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-snmpnetstat/

E.g :

```
$ snmpnetstat -v2c -c public -Cs -Cp udp 192.168.0.49
udp:
          1052 total datagrams received
          1167 datagrams to invalid port
             0 datagrams dropped due to errors
          1152 output datagram requests
```

From there you can parse the output and/or format it according to Cacti requirements.

---

Edit :

In case it returns no values like so :

```
tcp:
udp:
ip:
             - datagrams input
             - octets received
             - hdr errors input
             - no routes input
....
```

This is besause you have to allow queries on these statistics (OIDs) in your snmp agent config file.

E.g in `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf` add either :

- For UDP only :

  ```
   view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.7
  ```
- For All :

  ```
   view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1
  ```

Ref : https://oidref.com/1.3.6.1.2.1

Then restart your snmp agent to apply changes.

Comment: thanks! One issue please, how do I parse the output to cacti? Any tutorial useful you may have?

Comment: The script should output this format `<fieldname_1>:<value_1> <fieldname_2>:<value_2> ... <fieldname_n>:<value_n>`.
https://www.cacti.net/downloads/docs/html/making_scripts_work_with_cacti.html

Comment: I edited my question after issue which I've got after running `snmpnetstat `

Comment: @Tim Luka I've edited my answer for this issue

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my question, just couple of issues I faced while adding the data source.

Comment: Regarding your script it does not output in the required Cacti format (are you showing the full script ?)

Comment: yes, I am! This is actually the output: `Received Datagrams:258 Invalid port:63 Dropped datagrams:0 Datagram requests:471520`

Comment: By the way!, how shall be the input of bash script? in my case, I have it like this `rs="$(snmpnetstat -v2c -c public -Cs -Cp udp "$@")"` and when I ran the bash script I use the following `./upd_script.sh ip_address`. On the other hand, is it correct to run bash script of Input String at Data Input Method with the following path: `<path_cacti>scripts/udp_netstat.sh <host> `